# Where is the second parameter coming from in arrow function returning another arrow function in react with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux-form, higher-order-functions

I don't understand where the (val) is coming from in the returned arrow function.  I get that the max/minLength is an arrow function taking in a argument set on the input field(3 and 25) and it's returning an arrow function with a parameter called val but where is the argument for this.  I don't see where it is passed or coming from?  I'm new to redux and redux-from so I'm not sure if it has something to do with this or just plain es6 JS.  Thanks

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem, Button, Form, Row, Label, Col, FormFeedback} from 'reactstrap'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Control, LocalForm, Errors} from 'react-redux-form';

const required = (val) => val && val.length;
const maxLength = (len) => (val) => !(val) || (val.length <= len);
const minLength = (len) => (val) => (val) && (val.length >= len);
const isNumber = (val) => !isNaN(Number(val));
const validEmail = (val) => /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(val);

class Contact extends Component {
    handleSubmit = (values) => {
        console.log("Current state is:" + JSON.stringify(values));
        alert("Current state is:" + JSON.stringify(values));
    }
    
    render() {
        <LocalForm onSubmit={(values) => this.handleSubmit(values)}>
            <Row className="form-group">
                <Label htmlFor="firstname" md={2}>First Name</Label>
                <Col md={10}>
                    <Control.text model=".firstname" className="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname"
                                  placeholder="First Name"
                                  validators={{required, minLength: minLength(3), maxLength: maxLength(25)}}/>
                    <Errors className="text-danger" model=".firstname" show="touched" messages={{
                        required: 'Required',
                        minLength: 'Must be greater than 2 Characters',
                        maxLength: 'Must be 25 Characters or less'
                    }}/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
```

Comment: See the documentation for `validators` of `Control.text`. It's call them with the current input value.

Comment: i.e maxLength: you call the function, store the 25 in the closure scope and return a new function which will be called multiple times always with that 25 defined as the base

Answer (score 2):

A function returning another function is used to generate different variations of that particular function to be applied to different scenarios.

It's almost like a function factory.

It might be easier to digest what's going on if you expand the arrow functions into the standard function syntax that they represent.

```
function maxLength(len) {
  return function(val) {
    return !(val) || (val.length <= len);
  }
}
```

You can see that both arguments `len` and `val` are available on the third line for the conditional check. As far as the code in the innermost function is concerned, all the arguments taken before it are always fully available.

Below you can see how this `maxLength` function can be used in practice to perform different checks based on what the first argument means to you.

If your script has a concept of what a "long" array is and what a "short" array is, this is how it would work:

```
const isShortArray = maxLength(2); // `isShortArray(val)` is now a new function
const isLongArray = maxLength(4); // same core function, different context

isShortArray(['foo']); // true, array `val` has fewer elements than number `len` which was set to 2
isShortArray(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']); // false, `len` of maxLength exceeded

isLongArray(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']); // true, this time `len` is different
isLongArray(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'foo']); // false, val.length > 4 again
```

This is very similar to the technique called **currying** in functional programming languages. You can read more about that in JavaScript [here](https://javascript.info/currying-partials).

Comment: 'function curry(a) { 
    return function(b) {
      return a+b;
    };
  };
}
curry(1)(2)'
So usually there are two calls in currying which I don't have in my code... I'm understanding what you are saying, but I still don't understand where the second parameter is coming from(val).  Whats the value of (val) in my code ex and where is it coming from?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JeromeCode: It looks like `Control.text` expects to be passed an object of functions. Look at `required`. Why are you not wondering where it does get `val` from as well? It's used in exactly the same way. The only difference is that it's "fixed" where as for `minLength` and `maxLength` you created a "function factory" so that they can operator on different min and max values. At some point `Control.text` will call those functions and pass the corresponding values.

Comment: That's a good question, so then (val) is auto passed by redux-form through Control.text?  I'll go read up on redux form I guess...?

Comment: @JeromeCode The `Control.text` prop `validators` is an object literal which contains, for example, the function `validators.minLength(val)`. On this object, you only pass the `val` array to this function because the `minLength(len)` function on the parent component `Contact` (which you posted) already created a curried function that knows the `len` parameter.